# only print lines with specific column not *

Tags: regex, perl, bash, awk

I've got a program that sends text to stdout. But I only want to keep those lines where the fifth column isn't '*'. That is the asterisk char, not the regex expression that catches everything. I can't seem to use escape for this, I've tried

```
./a.out |awk '$5!=* {print}'
awk: $5!=* {print}
awk:     ^ syntax error
./a.out |awk '$5!=\* {print}'
awk: $5!=\* {print}
awk:     ^ backslash not last character on line
```

Awk is of course not a requirement, but I thought this would be the simplest.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` is similar to most Algol/C-family languages; literal strings require string quotes.

```
awk '$5 != "*" {print}'
```

Comment: Since the default action for `awk` is to print, you could simply write: `awk '$5 != "*"` filename

Comment: You do not need the print command, it is the default in awk: `awk '$5 != "*"'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
awk '$5!="*"{print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
perl -ane 'print unless $F[4] eq q(*)' file
```

The `-n` switch wraps this loop aaround your script to read the filename argument(s) on the command line:

```
LINE:
while (<>) {
    ... # your script here
}
```

The `-a` arms an autosplit of the line (on whitespace) into a predeclared array called `@F.  Unlike`awk` $F[0] is the first field only.

The `-e` argument is simply your script.

Comment: The `-n` switch adds this loop around your script to read one or more filename arguments:

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you:

```
awk '$5 !~ /^[*]$/' file
```

Comment: @kaz the intention was to show that the `*` could be shown unquoted as a class character

Comment: It's hardly unquoted. It's wrapped inside [], which is wrapped inside ^$, which is wrapped inside //.

Comment: @kaz `[]` represents a class, `^$` start/end of string and `//` are regexp delimiters. None of these are quotes.

Comment: quote, delimiter: potato, potaato.